# definitions of Re(z) and Im(z)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to derive a formula for Re(z) or Im(z) that does not use Re(z) or Im(z) in the formula? If so, what is it?

In other words, given any complex number z, where z = a+bi, and a and b are both real numbers, 
can we find a or b without using functions like Re(z), Im(z) or abs(z) (because abs(z) uses Re and Im in its definition)

Edit:I did not consider complex conjugation when writing this. I don't "accept" it because it is a function in terms of the individual real and imaginary components of z.

Comment: How about $\text{Re}(z) = (z + \overline{z})/2$?

Comment: Or if you don't want to allow complex conjugation, why not tell us what we **are** allowed to use rather than what we aren't?

Comment: If you are given $z$ in the form of $a+bi$ , you don't really need a formula to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $abs(z)= \sqrt{z \bar z}$ does not use Re and Im.

Comment: Whats the motivation for the question?

Comment: @Robert Israel Obviously I can't list every single mathematical formula that can be used here, but in short, you can use any function that can be calculated without taking the real and imaginary components of a number individually.

Comment: This is a curious requirement. Why would you need a formula for such obviously available quantities?

Answer (score 11):

If you ''accept'' complex conjugation, then
$$\Re(z)=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$$
and
$$\Im(z)=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}$$

Comment: conversely, if OP doesn't "'accept complex conjugation," then he's probably asking if there is a holomorphic formula for them, and then the answer is no.

Comment: Indeed, this is a good point!

Comment: To clarify, no, complex conjugates are not allowed because they are defined in terms of the real and imaginary components of a number.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on that you mean by *formula*. In a wide sense, as argued below, the answer is *no*.

Indeed, $\Re(z)$ is not a holomorphic function since its image is the real line.
In this sense, there is no formula for $\Re(z)$ that does not involve $\bar z$, because 
the Cauchy–Riemann equations fail for $\Re(z)$:
$$
{\frac {\partial \Re(z)}{\partial {\bar {z}}}}=\frac12 \ne 0
$$

Comment: This was said already in the comments.

Comment: @amsmath, we should avoid using comments to answer questions.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Riemann_equations#Independence_of_the_complex_conjugate

Comment: But you didn't actually answer the question. OP never mentioned the complex conjugate.

Comment: @amsmath, indeed. Let's hope the OP clarifies what kinds of formula are acceptable.

Comment: To clarify, no, complex conjugates are not allowed because they are defined in terms of the real and imaginary components of a number.

Comment: @LUCASSWANSON But you don't have to define complex conjugation in terms of real and imaginary parts. You could define it as the unique nontrivial continuous automorphism of the ring C.